# require class name in rspec-puppet

Tags: rspec, puppet

I have two different manifests files one is with define and the other one is normal manifests.

Here they use `require classname` in normal manifests.

```
class bfile { 
  require dummy 
  if $::operatingsystemmajrelease > 5 { 

    file {'/some/path/foo': 
      ensure => present, 
      owner => 'root', 
      group => 'root', 
      mode => '0644', 
    }
  }
}
```

I tried `it {should contain_class('dummy')}` and `it {should contain_require('dummy')}`,

but I'm getting `"Could not find class dummy on node"` error.

Is there any option available in `puppet-rspec` to check `require classname`?

Comment: Can you try and be more specific? (Example code?) I have literally no idea what you issue is.

Comment: Please add all additional information by editing the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Could not find class dummy on node` might signify that the `class dummy` is not in your `modulepath`. It's recommended to use absolute scope and modules: `require ::my_module::dummy`. The class should be defined in:

```
modules/my_module/manifests/dummy.pp
```

Regarding the second part, `require` will cause that Puppet will ensure that every resource in the `bfile` class gets applied before every resource in any `dummy` class.

Which means that you should be able to test it this way (RSpec >= 3 syntax):

```
it { is_expected.to contain_file('/some/path/foo').that_requires('Class[bfile]') }
```